# Factorial minimisation

Tags: inequality, factorial

What methods might be appropriate to find the lowest integer bound for $t$ in the following inequality for a given $p$?

$(2t+2)! > 2^{p+1}$

The best I can do is by using the inverse gamma function:

$$ \begin{align} 
(2t+2)! & > 2^{p+1} \\ 
\Gamma(2t+3) & > 2^{p+1} \\
2t+3 & > \Gamma^{-1}(2^{p+1}) \\
t & > \frac{\Gamma^{-1}(2^{p+1}) - 3}2
\end{align} $$

Giving the minimum bound on $t$ to be $\lceil{\frac{\Gamma^{-1}(2^{p+1}) - 3}2}\rceil$

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to left align implication signs, so they're left out, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) ?

Answer (score 1):

David Cantrell gave a very good approximation of the inverse gamma function [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171104030158/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=342551&tstart=0). It is $$\Gamma^{-1}(x)=\frac{L(x)}{W\left(\frac{L(x)}{e}\right)}+\frac{1}{2}$$ using $$L(x)=\log \left(\frac{x+0.036534}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\right)$$ $W(z)$ being Lambert function for which good approximations can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

I hope and wish this could help you.